# AWS Cognito: How to create new DataSet using PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm using PHP SDK to implement AWS Cognito custom authorizer for my client.

I'm able to list datasets and records for each identity created but I couldn't find any way to create a new dataset and add records in it.

There are methods in other SDKs though for creating new dataset. e.g. Android: `Dataset dataset = client.openOrCreateDataset("datasetname");`

Are there any equivalent methods in PHP for the same?

Answer (score 0):

I am on the Cognito team. Cognito Sync doesn't have a high level SDK for PHP. You can still call the low level APIs from PHP. These are described here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/service-cognitosync.html

Comment: Is there any plan to add missing APIs in SDK?